# Given a filtration of an $R$-module, I need help proving a particular finiteness condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings, filtrations

Given a filtration $F_{\bullet}M$ of an $R$-module $M$ (where $R$ itself is a filtered algebra with filtration $F_{\bullet}R$) which is

$\bullet$ exhaustive: i.e., $\cup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}F_iM = M$,

$\bullet$ separated: i.e., $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}F_iM=\{0\}$, and

$\bullet$ compatible, i.e., $F_iR \cdot F_jM \subseteq F_{i+j}M$,

If the associated graded $R$-module $$\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^FM = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{gr}_{i}^FM, \quad \mathrm{gr}_{i}^FM:=F_iM/F_{i-1}M$$ is finitely generated over $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^FR=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0}F_iR/F_{i-1}R$, then it can be shown (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800970/how-can-i-prove-that-if-m-is-a-graded-r-module-then-each-m-i-is-also-fini)) that each $\mathrm{gr}_{i}^F M$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{gr}_{0}^FR=F_0R$ and $\mathrm{gr}_{i}^F M = \{0\}$ for all $i\ll 0$.

**Question:** How can I show that $F_iM=\{0\}$ for all $i\ll 0$ and that all of the $F_iM$ are finitely generated over $F_0R$?

Comment: Do you assume that the hypotheses of the statement you quote just above your question hold?

Comment: @Mindlack: I'm not sure which hypotheses exactly you're talking about. If you mean $\mathrm{gr}_{i}^F M$ is f.g. over $F_i R$, then yes, I'm assuming that holds.

Comment: Then $gr_i\,M=0$ for small enough $i$, so that for small enough $i$, $F_iM=F_{i-1}M$. As the filtration is separated, it follows that for small enough $i$, $F_iM=0$. For the second part, use induction and consider the exact sequence of $F_0R$-modules: $0 \rightarrow F_{i-1}M \rightarrow F_iM \rightarrow gr_iM \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Mindlack: Thank you, using the S.E.S. is very clever and I certainly wouldn't thought of using it. I'm not seeing how $F_iM=F_{i-1}M$ and seperatedness combine to prove $F_iM=0$? Can you explain some more, I'm obviously missing something obvious.

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning now. It's like we're going down the filtration and at some point the components of the filtration stabilize. If we haven't reached zero yet, how can it then be possible that $\cap F_iM=0$?

Comment: Yes, that’s it for both comments.

Comment: @Mindlack: Suppose we knew for $i>0$ that $gr_{i+1}^{F}M = gr_{1}^{F}R \cdot gr_i^F M$ , do you know how this allows us to write $F_{i+1} M=F_{1} R \cdot F_{i} M + F_iM$? I'm confused as to how we'd get this relation given the above. I'm sorry if it's not cool to ask you unrelated questions like this, I'd open a separate question if you mind me asking.

Comment: This looks like “abstract nonsense“ (but in abstract algebra especially this doesn’t mean it’s necessarily obvious). Let $x \in F_{i+1}M$. Its class in $gr_{i+1}(M)$ is generated by products of classes of elements of $F_1R$ and classes of elements of $F_iM$. In other words, the class of $x$ is the class of some element $y$ of $F_1R \cdot F_iM$. Two elements of $F_{i+1}M$ have the same class iff their difference is in $F_iM$, so $x \in y +F_iM$, which prives your claim.

Comment: @Mindlack: Thank you so much. That's perfectly clear. Before your comment, I asked the following question because I thought you might not answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805072/need-help-understanding-the-structure-of-this-finitely-generated-graded-algebra/3805185#3805185