# Need help understanding the structure of this finitely generated graded algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Suppose $R$ is a ring with filtration $F_{\bullet}R$: $$
\{0\} \subseteq F_0R \subseteq F_1R \subseteq \cdots \subseteq F_{n}R \subseteq \cdots \subseteq R.
$$
Let $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R$ be the associated graded algebra $$
\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R:=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{gr}_{i}^{F}R \quad \text{where}\; \mathrm{gr}_{i}^{F}R:=F_{i}R/F_{i-1}R \;\text{and}\; \mathrm{gr}_{0}^{F}R:=F_{0}R. 
$$
Let $M$ be an $R$-module with filtration $F_{\bullet}M$: $$
\cdots \subseteq F_{i}M \subseteq F_{i+1}M \subseteq \cdots \subseteq M \quad (i \in \mathbb{Z})
$$ such that $\bigcup_{j} F_{j}M=M, \bigcap_{j}F_{j}M=\{0\}$ and $F_{i}R\cdot F_{j}M\subseteq F_{i+j}M$ for all $i\ge 0$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We form the associated graded $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R$-module: $$
\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}M:=\bigoplus_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{gr}_{j}^{F}M \quad \text{where}\; \mathrm{gr}_{j}^{F}M:=F_{j}M/F_{j-1}M 
$$
The module structure is given by $$\mathrm{gr}_{i}^{F}R \cdot \mathrm{gr}_{j}^{F}M \subseteq \mathrm{gr}_{i+j}^{F}M \quad \text{for all}\; i,j \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

**Question**: If $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}M$ is finitely generated over $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R$, (1) why/how is it that we can write $$
\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}M=\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R \cdot \bigoplus_{j\le j_0} \mathrm{gr}_{j}^{F}M \quad \text{for some}\; j_0 \in \mathbb{Z}?$$ and (2) how does it follow from this that:

$$\mathrm{gr}_{l+1}^{F}M = \sum_{j\le j_0} \mathrm{gr}_{l+1-j}^{F}R \cdot \mathrm{gr}_{j}^{F}M \subseteq \mathrm{gr}_{1}^{F}R \cdot \mathrm{gr}_{l}^{F}M
$$
for all $l \ge j_0$?

Finally, (3) obviously the above inclusion implies that $\mathrm{gr}_{l+1}^{F}M = \mathrm{gr}_{1}^{F}M \cdot \mathrm{gr}_{l}^{F}M$, but then why does it follow  from this that $$F_{l+1}R = F_1R \cdot F_l M + F_l M \subseteq F_1R \cdot F_l M?$$

I'm extremely sorry is this is too many questions. I wouldn't ask so many, but they're all very related and I think it would be best to ask them together.

---

EDIT: Problem (1) when I think a little hard about seems like obviously true and I don't believe requires any justification.

For problem (2), the equality in the displayed formula follows directly from above, but I don't understand how you get the inclusion.

For problem (3), from a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801093/given-a-filtration-of-an-r-module-i-need-help-proving-a-particular-finiteness?noredirect=1&lq=1) of @Mindlack, how the equality is obtained is answered. I don't know about the inclusion still.

Comment: Are you sure you stated all assumptions? It would help if you disclosed your sources. Where does this question come from?

Comment: @Claudius: Yes, all the assumptions are included and see page 4, prop 2.13 of the link for source of frustration (I've only made minor changes, as you can tell) : http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/mat615/lectures/lecture2.pdf

Comment: and problem (1) comes from prop 1.16, pg 71 in this book: https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=XN_FCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Algebraic+Approach+Differential+Equations+trang&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi999mfybvrAhXJV30KHZZuBs8Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=Algebraic%20Approach%20Differential%20Equations%20trang&f=false (unfortunately the page I wanted to show you isn't available for free preview.)

Comment: In your first source it says that the filtration of the ring $R$ is either the order filtration or the Bernstein filtration. Both have the property that $F_iR\cdot F_jR = F_{i+j}R$ for all $i,j$. This is important for question (2), so you should add this assumption.

Comment: What about question (1) is it that you don't understand? I would say it is immediate, so if you could elaborate on the problem, this would drastically improve a possible answer.

Comment: Also in your last displayed formula, $F_{l+1}R$ should be $F_{l+1}M$, right?

Comment: @Claudius: Yes, you're absolutely right. I'm sorry I missed that. We're assuming that the filtration is either the Bernstein filtration or order the order filtration.

Comment: My confusion with problem (1) is that I too can tell/sense (through some hand-wavy logic) that that should be true. I wasn't too sure if it's really that obvious. I'll try to put some reasoning for why I think that would be true in the body of the question. You're right about the last displayed formula also. I'll fix the typo.

Comment: Another question that also comes to mind is: is it also true that $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^{F}R$ is commutative iff $F_iR \cdot F_jR= F_{i+j}R$ for all $i, j$? I'll rather make the commutativity assumption since I think that's the direction the notes are headed - we're trying to avoid studying our non-commutative algebras and wishing for a commutative substitute.

Comment: I don't think there is any relation. The trivial filtration on a non-commutative ring $R$, i.e., $F_iR = \{0\}$ for $i< 0$ and $F_iR = R$ for $i\ge0$, has the property that $F_iR\cdot F_jR = F_{i+j}R$ for all $i,j$, but ${\mathrm {gr}}^F_\bullet R$ is non-commutative (because it is just $R$ viewed as a graded ring concentrated in degree $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\gr}{\operatorname{gr}}$
For question (2) you have to use $\gr^F_iR\cdot \gr^F_jR = \gr^F_{i+j}R$ for all $i,j$, which follows from the (still missing) assumption that $F_iR\cdot F_jR = F_{i+j}R$ for all $i,j$. Indeed, given $l\ge j_0$ and $j\le j_0$, we then have
$$
\gr^F_{l+1-j}R\cdot \gr^F_jM = \gr^F_1R\cdot \gr^F_{l-j}\cdot \gr^F_jM \subseteq \gr^F_1R\cdot \gr^F_lM.
$$
Hence, taking the sum over all $l\ge j_0$ yields the claim.

Ad (3): We have $\gr^F_{l+1}M = \gr^F_1R\cdot \gr^F_lM$. By writing out how $\gr^F_\bullet R$ acts on $\gr^F_\bullet M$, you see that this is equivalent to
$$
F_{l+1}M = F_1R\cdot F_lM + F_lM.
$$
To be more explicit: Recall that $\gr^F_lM = F_lM/F_{l-1}M$ and similarly $\gr_1R = F_1R/F_0R$. Then $\gr^F_{l+1}M = \gr^F_1R\cdot \gr^F_lM$ means that for every $m+F_lM \in \gr^F_{l+1}M$ there exist $r_1,\dotsc,r_n\in F_1R$ and $m_1,\dotsc,m_n\in F_lM$ such that
$$
m+F_lM = \sum_{i=1}^n r_im_i + F_lM.
$$
But then $m - \sum_{i=1}^nr_im_i = m'\in F_lM$, i.e., $m = \sum_{i=1}^n r_im_i + m'$. This shows $F_{l+1}M \subseteq F_1R\cdot F_lM + F_lM$. The other inclusion follows from the definition of a filtration of a module.

But notice that $1 \in F_0R \subseteq F_1R$ (this is true for the order filtration and the Bernstein filtration in your source, but regardless of that it should be part of the definition of “filtration of a ring”). Hence, $F_lM \subseteq F_1R\cdot F_lM$, so that finally
$$
F_{l+1}M = F_1R\cdot F_lM.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can I ask of you to please, if possible, explain some more how the action of $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^F R$ on $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}^F M$ gives us the equality? Everything else is very understandable.

Comment: I suspected that in (3) the reasoning for the inclusion could be that $1 \in F_0R \subseteq F_1 R$ but thought we couldn't make the assumption in this case.